# Find exact element position in Dataframe by row and column index

Tags: python, dataframe

I have a dataframe (650,650) whch look like the one depicted.
I need to find elements that has the same column and row name(label/index... call it what you like) and make them equal zero.

```
       car0     car1    car2     car3
car0     0      0,25    0,83      2

car1    1,23     0      0,83      0

car2    6,83    0,25     0        5

car3    0,23    0,55     0,43     0

car2    12        2      0        0,5

car2    0,5       2      0       0,5
```

could someone help?

i have been iterating through columns and rows but with no use.

```
for c,col in df2.iterrows():
    for r,row in df2.iteritems():
        if df2.loc[:,c]== df2[r,:]:
            df2.loc[row,col] = 0
        else: break
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Updated answer after question was updated:

First, get a set of unique values which feature in both the index and column names:

```
names = set(df.columns).intersection(df.index)
```

Then iterate over them, using `.loc` to set values:

```
for name in names:
    df.loc[name, name] = 0
```

This is similar to the answer by @Valentino, with an amendment to make sure that we only loop over each name once.

---

Original answer which assumed that we just had to fill the diagonal:

You could use [`np.fill_diagonal`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.fill_diagonal.html) for this to avoid a loop:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.random(size=(5, 5)))
np.fill_diagonal(df.values, 0)
```

Results:

```
          0         1         2         3         4
0  0.000000  0.707695  0.275748  0.449722  0.321772
1  0.343112  0.000000  0.051894  0.879492  0.210940
2  0.845859  0.016546  0.000000  0.347568  0.233525
3  0.483467  0.094216  0.583731  0.000000  0.242194
4  0.638833  0.382917  0.321501  0.190206  0.000000
```

Comment: thanks, but it didn't change my dataframe:
df2 = pd.DataFrame(distance_matrix(df.values, df.values), index=df.index, columns=df.index)

Comment: `np.fill_diagonal(df2.values, 0)` should work for you. I called my DataFrame in the above example `df` rather than `df2`.

Comment: yes, i am aware, thanks. but I have the feeling I should elaborate more: 
the df is already diagonal, meaning my diagonal is already zeros. the rows are basically repetitions so the row name is repeated 100 of times but not in a systematic way. So at the end I will be comparing my column name with hunderds of rows untill i find the rows that have the same name and delete that single element position (same col and same row name).... hope it helped

Comment: I have edited my answer, hopefully that works now - my original idea of filling the diagonal does not work with your new posted dataset.

Comment: it worked exactly as intended! thanks @thesilkworm!

Answer (score 2):

From your example seems that columns and rows have the same labels. If so, you can use:

```
for i in df.columns:
    df[i][i] = 0
```

This works even if labels are not in the same order (such that zeroes should not appear on the diagonal).

In case there are column labels which do not appear as row labels and viceversa, you need a little more elaborate solution:

```
for i in df.columns:
    try:
        df.loc[i].loc[i] = 0
    except KeyError:
        pass
```

In case you have repeated names on rows or columns, please refer to [@thesilkworm's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56951356/10426037). You may also use `unique()` istead of `set`, but the idea is the same.

```
for i in df.index.unique().intersection(df.columns.unique()):
    df.loc[i, i] = 0
```

Comment: thanks but it didn't help. 
error: A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame.
Try using .loc[row_indexer,col_indexer] = value instead..

regardless of the error, the dataframe haven't changed 
for more info, this is the df,  
df2 = pd.DataFrame(distance_matrix(df.values, df.values), index=df.index, columns=df.index)

Comment: In my solution, the dataframe `df` is the one you posted. The one you call `df2`.

Comment: I am aware, thanks. I edited the figure in my question so it's more clear.

Comment: Ah, so you have repeated names. That's something you should have said before. In that case, please use the updated solution of @thesilkworm, that's the correct way to do it.